# Error while using render() on the response's html recieved from AsyncHTMLSession

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

The code:(error on the line results[0].html.render()) render worked when previously i didnt use AsyncHTMLSession , but  had used HTMLSession.

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

link="https://www.daraz.com.np/catalog/?q={}"
asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
async def get_daraz():
    r = await asession.get(link.format("mouse"))
    return r
results = asession.run(get_daraz)


results[0].html.render()
```

error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ZinonYT/PycharmProjects/testTags/tags.py", line 11, in <module>
    results[0].html.render()
  File "C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\testTags\venv\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 598, in render
    content, result, page = self.session.loop.run_until_complete(self._async_render(url=self.url, script=script, sleep=sleep, wait=wait, content=self.html, reload=reload, scrolldown=scrolldown, timeout=timeout, keep_page=keep_page))
  File "C:\Users\ZinonYT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\testTags\venv\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 505, in _async_render
    page = await self.browser.newPage()
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'newPage'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseSession.browser' was never awaited
```

Answer (score 2):

results[0].html.render() instead of this do

```
await r.html.arender()
```

but in the async function because await only allowed inside async functions .